# Concatenate 2 vectors at a specific index

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

I have 2 vectors, which may look like this:

```
v1 <- c( 1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 )
v2 <- c( 1,1,0,1,0,1 )
```

now i want to concatenate these 2 vectors in that way:

```
res <- concat( v2, v1, begin = 3 ) #concat is the searched function
res ==  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
       [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
        v2  v2  v2  v2  v2  v2  v1  v1  v1  v1  v1  v1  v1  v1
```

The function concats v2 and v1, from the parameter "begin".
How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 c(v2, v1[3:length(v1)])
```

Or as a function

```
  concat <- function(vec2, vec1, begin){
   c(vec2, vec1[begin:length(vec1)])
   }

  concat(v2, v1, 3)
  #[1] 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```